# Update div on event

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using the jquery slider and using append() to update the value, but it will keep adding it unless I empty it on the start event. Is there a way where I can just updated the value instead of printing it out every time the action takes place. i tried replaceWith but no luck there.

```
start: function(event, ui){
    $('#current_value').empty();    
},
slide: function(event, ui){
    $('#current_value').fadeIn().append('Value is '+ui.value);
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like

```
slide: function(event, ui){
    $('#current_value').text('Value is '+ui.value);
    $('#current_value').fadeIn();
}
```

[text()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text#val) documentation

Comment: Thank you for that. Works great so far. HTML also works too from what I see on the other answers. Just a different method?

Comment: As the documentation states: "Similar to html(), but escapes HTML (replace "<" and ">" with their HTML entities). Cannot be used on input elements. "

Answer (score 1):

you need to use html() not append(), append adds the value at end of the given element, html sets the innerHtml for the given element.

$('#current_value').html('Value is '+ui.value).fadeIn();

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, you should:

```
var existing = $('#current_value').html();
$('#current_value').html(existing + ui.value).fadeIn();
```